# Problemas con librería mpAndroidChart. Cuadro de mpAndroidChart se encoje al hacer un click o zom

Tags: android

Tengo un problema con mi MpAndroidChart. El punto es que cada vez que hago un click o un zom el cuadro de chart, éste se encoje. Lo malo también es que mientras mas barras haya más se encoje.

[image: En esta imagen se muestra el cuadro completo]
[image: En esta otra imagen se ha achicado el cuadro del chart se puede notar al ver la diferencia en la distancia que hay entre el cuadro del chart y las leyendas.]

Pr favor podrían ayudarme  a solucionar este problema? Es urgente.

Les adjunto mi código en android. Muchas gracias.

```
public class DistributionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String access_token;
    private HorizontalBarChart chart;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals3 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals4 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    BarData data = null;


    float barWidth;
    float barSpace;
    float groupSpace;
    double DbPercent;
    float percent;
    protected Typeface mTfLight;

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_distribution);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesG11", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ActionBar toolbar =  getSupportActionBar();
        toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", "");

        //tv_prueba=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_prueba);

        /**********components************/


        LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
        Call<UserAccountBean> call = loginService.getUserLogged(access_token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccountBean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Response<UserAccountBean> response) {
                UserAccountBean userAccountBean = response.body();
                //tv_prueba.setText(userAccountBean.getId()+" "+userAccountBean.getFirstName()+" "+userAccountBean.getPatternName() );


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        DistributionSummaryDataService dashBoardService = ServiceGenerator.createService(DistributionSummaryDataService.class);
        Call<ResponseBean<DistributionSummaryDataBean>> dbCall;
        dbCall = dashBoardService.getAllPercent(access_token);
        dbCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBean<DistributionSummaryDataBean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBean<DistributionSummaryDataBean>> call, Response<ResponseBean<DistributionSummaryDataBean>> response) {

                DistributionSummaryDataBean dsd = (DistributionSummaryDataBean) response.body().getData();

                System.out.println("====================================================================");

                chart= (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.distribution_chart);
              //  chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener((OnChartValueSelectedListener) contex);

                chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
                chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
                chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                chart.setScaleYEnabled(true);// zomm y
                chart.setScaleXEnabled(false);// zomm x
                chart.setDrawBarShadow(false); //sombra en las barras
                chart.setPinchZoom(false);
                chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);                //
                chart.animateY(5000);
                chart.setClickable(false);


                xVals.add(dsd.getaLastMonthBean().getStrMonth());
                xVals.add(dsd.getaLastWeekBean().getStrMonth());
                for (int i = 0 ; i<dsd.getLstLastSevenDayBean().size();i++) {
                    xVals.add(dsd.getLstLastSevenDayBean().get(i).getStrDate());

                }
                xVals.add(dsd.getaDistributionSummaryDataBean().getStrDateData());
/*barras*/
                DbPercent = dsd.getaLastMonthBean().getDbPercent();
                percent = (float) DbPercent;
                yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0,  (float)Math.round(percent*100)/100));

                DbPercent = dsd.getaLastWeekBean().getDbPercent();
                percent = (float) DbPercent;
                yVals2.add(new BarEntry(1,  (float)Math.round(percent*100)/100));
               int a=2;
                for (int i = 0 ; i<dsd.getLstLastSevenDayBean().size();i++) {
                    DbPercent = dsd.getLstLastSevenDayBean().get(i).getDbPercent();
                    percent = (float) DbPercent;
                    yVals3.add(new BarEntry(a, (float) Math.round(percent * 100)));
                    a++;
                }

                DbPercent =  dsd.getaDistributionSummaryDataBean().getDbPercent();
                percent = (float) DbPercent;
                yVals4.add(new BarEntry(9, (float) Math.round(percent * 100) / 100));

                System.out.println("last month percent -> "+(float)Math.round(percent*100)/100+ " - "+DbPercent);

                barWidth = 0.3f;
                barSpace = 0f;
                groupSpace = 0.2f;

                BarDataSet set1, set2,set3,set4;
                set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Mes pasado" );
                set1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2,"Semana pasada");
                set2.setColor(Color.CYAN);

                set3 = new BarDataSet(yVals3,"7 días antes");
                set3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

                set4 = new BarDataSet(yVals4,"Mes actual");
                set4.setColor(Color.RED);

                data = new BarData(set1, set2,set3,set4 );
                data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0")));
                chart.setData(data);
                chart.setFitBars(true);
                //chart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
            //    chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
              //  chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(1);


                System.out.println("xval: " + set1 + " yval: " + set2);



                Legend l = chart.getLegend();
                l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
                l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
                l.setYOffset(20f);
                l.setXOffset(0f);
                l.setDrawInside(false);
                l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
                l.setFormSize(9f);
                l.setTextSize(11f);
                l.setXEntrySpace(6f);

                //X-axis


                XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
                xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
                xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
                xAxis.setLabelCount(20);
                xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(90f);
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));

//Y-axis
                LimitLine limitline = new LimitLine(95);
                limitline.setLabel("95 %");
                limitline.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_TOP);
                limitline.setLineWidth(4f);
                limitline.setTextSize(15f);

                YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
                leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
                leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                leftAxis.addLimitLine(limitline);
                leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter( new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0")));


                YAxis yr = chart.getAxisRight();
                yr.setTypeface(mTfLight);
                yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
                yr.setAxisMinimum(0f);
                yr.setAxisMaximum(100f);
                yr.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter( new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0")));


                /***********************CHART END*************************************/

                /***********************CHART*************************************/
                System.out.println("====================================================================");
                chart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBean<DistributionSummaryDataBean>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.err.println("ERRORORORORRO: " + t.toString());
                System.err.println("ERRORORORORRO: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes desactivar el zoom y manejarlo tu mismo como te paresca mejor en tu codigo seria algo asi

```
chart.zoom(valores pra X,valores para Y, valores para x ,valores para y)
float groupSpace = 0.08f;
        float barSpace = 0.03f; // x4 DataSet
        float barWidth = 0.2f; // x4 DataSet
        // (0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00 -> interval por  "group"
```

esto es un ejemplo de los repos oficiales de mpandroidchart saca tus cuentas para que las barras se distribuyan bien en tu grafico y para terminar 
solo usa esto

```
chart.setDescription(null);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        chart.zoom(X, Y, x, y);
```

en las propiedades de tu chart y empiezas a observar el comportamiento de tu grafica